# shouldn't `where.not(field: "something")` include `where(field: nil)`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, arel

Perhaps I'm going crazy, or just need a break, but in my rails console `Order.where(state: nil).count` returns `1010`, but `Order.where.not(state: "pending").count` returns `0`... If an order's state is nil, then it is not "pending", so I expect the set returned by `not(state: "pending")` to include the set `where(state: nil)`.

Does arel not work this way? If not, does arel work a different way?

EDIT: more info! When I go to another database, where some records have a state other than nil, and I run `Order.where.not(state: "pending").count` I get back a bunch of orders, none of which are "pending" but also none of which are nil. It seems that `where.not` is implicitly adding a `and not nil` to the query?

EDIT: in desperation, I have turned to darker spirits.

```
# look into another shop, that has records
o = Order.where(shop_id: 2)

# summon dread spirits
t = Order.arel_table[:state]

o.where(t.eq(nil).or(t.eq("pending").not)).count

=> 1569

o.where(t.eq(nil)).count

=> 1471
```

So in this case, I get the 98 records whose status is neither nil nor "pending", and I get all the records whose status is nil. I would really like to know why I can't just say `where.not("pending")` and have the same effect. If there maybe an option I can invoke? Like, `where.not("pending", include_nil: true)`?

EDIT: as requested in a comment by @Filip Bartuzi

```
Order.where.not(state: "pending").to_sql

=> "SELECT \"orders\".* FROM \"orders\"  WHERE \"orders\".\"shop_id\" = 2 AND (\"orders\".\"state\" != 'pending')"

Orders.where(state: nil).to_sql

=> "SELECT \"orders\".* FROM \"orders\"  WHERE \"orders\".\"shop_id\" = 2 AND \"orders\".\"state\" IS NULL"
```

Comment: Are you sure there is only `NULL`/`'pending'` value in database? Check it this way: `Order.pluck(:state)`

Comment: Unfortunately I have no access to rails environment so I can't test it by my own but could you please paste what's value of `Order.where.not(status: "pending").to_sql` and `Order.where(status:nil)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Order.where.not(state: "pending").to_sql` generates:

`=> "SELECT \"orders\".* FROM \"orders\"  WHERE \"orders\".\"shop_id\" = 2 AND (\"orders\".\"state\" != 'pending')"`

It will return all records with VALUES which are not 'pending'. When u set `pending` to `nil` (like `Order.first.update! state: nil` it assigns `NULL` in database.

`NULL` isn't interpreted as value in SQL so it will not be included in `SELECT` response

So the answer is : `where.not(field: “something”)` does NOT include `where(field: nil)`!

You can check how it works here:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all

Go to the categories table and firstly execute

```
UPDATE Categories
SET CategoryName = NULL
WHERE CategoryName = 'Beverages'
```

So now we have Categories of Count 8 which one of them has `NULL` on column `CategoryName`

Now execute:

```
SELECT CategoryName FROM Categories
WHERE CategoryName != 'Condiments'
```

As you see 6 records where returned (so it skipped one with `NULL`)

Comment: OK, so to include both values that are not a thing, and non-values, I must always jump to the arel_table style `or` queries? Or is there another way?

Comment: Firstly I think you should NOT represent any value as NULL. So if your Order can be either 'pending' or 'canceled' you should store 'canceled' it as string or as a number representation. If you use Rails 4 I would recommend using `enum` on Order model

Comment: ah OK, I was using nil as the default state but you are correct that the default state should be an actual state. Good advice.

Answer (score 2):

SQL implementations follow 3 valued logic where NULL is not a value but marks the absence of a value. 3 valued logic defines the following truth table for logical operations: (null is Unknown here)

```
p       |q      |p OR q |p AND q|p = q
True    |True   |True   |True   |True
True    |False  |True   |False  |False
True    |Unknow |True   |Unknown|Unknown
False   |True   |True   |False  |False
False   |False  |False  |False  |True
False   |Unknown|Unknown|False  |Unknown
Unknown |True   |True   |Unknown|Unknown
Unknown |False  |Unknown|False  |Unknown
Unknown |Unknown|Unknown|Unknown|Unknown
```

Since `where` tests for equality (`row.state == 'pending'`) on each entry in the data set, by the truth table above if row.state is `NULL` the result is 'Unknown'. 'Unknown' isn't true so the row isn't included in the result set.

More info at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)#Comparisons_with_NULL_and_the_three-valued_logic_.283VL.29).