# Rails 4: model.where.not does not return nil records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I've done a google search and found similar questions to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26371000/shouldnt-where-notfield-something-include-wherefield-nil), however, I am still lost as to what the solution should be. My case is following:

I have a database table called `Book` where it has `category_id` (foreign key to table `Category`) and `author` (varchar 255). I need to query this table by `category_id` but excluding certain author's name. Example: get all the books for category_id = 10 but excluding books by author John Doe:

```
books = Book.where(category_id: 10).where.not(author: 'John Doe')
```

or

```
books = Book.where(category_id: 10).where("author != ?", "John Doe")
```

These two queries work for me except on those records whose author is `nil`. I also need to have these queries return records that have `nil` author.

Comment: did you try this? books = Book.where(category_id: 10).where("author <> ? OR author = ?", "John Doe", nil)

Comment: `NULL` is unknown so you'll need to account for it specifically as per @chrismanderson's answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You were on the right track with the last query.

```
Book.where(category_id: 10).where("author != ? OR author IS NULL", "John Doe")
```

This should do what you are asking.

Side note, in Rails 5, you can use `or` with `ActiveRecord` queries, so you could so something like:

```
Book.where(category_id: 10).where.not(author: 'John Doe').or(where(author: nil))
```

Though I'd argue, in this case, the first query is clearer.

Comment: For a more object-oriented approach in Rails 4, you could also use [this gem](https://github.com/oelmekki/activerecord_any_of). See [this example](https://github.com/oelmekki/activerecord_any_of#dynamic-or-queries) for inspiration.

Comment: The reason here is that `'x'=NULL` is false but `'x'!=NULL` is also false. Basically `NULL` is not equal to nor unequal to other values including itself, so `IS NULL` is required.